# how to call a python bytecode file by boost.python or by python/c api

Tags: c++, python, c, boost-python

I have some python bytecode file as "a.pyc","b.pyc".I want to run this file in c++ code.
The code can call boost.python or python/c api.
PyEval_EvalCode?

```
PyObject* PyEval_EvalCode(PyCodeObject *co, PyObject *globals, PyObject *locals)
```

But how to get PyCodeObject from the bytecode file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this from the Very High Level layer. (Have you tried `PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags`?) So you want to look at the [Importing Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html) API.

If you're just trying to import `foo`, or do the equivalent importlib-ish stuff, without caring whether it's `foo.py` or `foo.pyc`, that's not too hard. But if you're trying to avoid the usual rules for import and explicitly specify the file by pathname… that must be possible, but I can't think of any way to do that… except:

A .pyc file is, under the covers, just the magic number from `PyImport_GetMagicNumber()`, then a 4-byte timestamp which you can ignore, then a marshalled code object, which you can `marshal.loads` from Python or `PyMarshal_ReadObjectFromString` from C.

I haven't tested this from C, but from Python:

```
>>> with open('foo.pyc', 'rb') as f:
...     data = f.read()
>>> code = marshal.loads(data[8:])
>>> code
<code object <module> at 0x110118730, file "foo.py", line 1>
```

And examining it, it seems to be exactly what it ought to be.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty well documented on the Python website:
http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html
http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_CallObject

The main idea is to initialize Python, then initialize the module ( PyImport_Import with your .pyc module), then PyOject_CallObject.

I'm assuming you have a specific method you'd like to call.

http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding

Comment: No, `Py_InitModule` does not create a code object from a .pyc file, it creates a module object from a name and a table of functions. It's what you use inside an extension module to export your module to Python, which has nothing to do with what the OP asked for.

Comment: I just copied the wrong one. PyImport_Import is what I meant.

Comment: @gregbeaty,This is not the suitable answer.

Comment: `PyImport_Import` isn't right either. This takes a PyObject* and calls the import hook function on it.